# Rails console doesn't start - undefiined method cache_control

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to run rails console but I get the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:89:in `<class:Response>': undefined method `cache_control' for class `ActionDispatch::Response' (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:35:in `<module:ActionDispatch>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller.rb:4:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:9:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/all.rb:14:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/all.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/isaac/buzzrails/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/isaac/buzzrails/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've tried restarting spring but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Edit:
This is my config/application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Buzzbomb
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

and this is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'json'
gem 'tux'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - appreciate any suggestions, running on a nginx server. It works locally but I get the error when I do "rails console" on the server.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.1.3

Comment: can you edit your question to show your config/application.rb and Gemfile contents?

Comment: yes @TomD I've added what you asked now

Comment: Is it only on the server when running rails console or on your dev machine also? @Isaac

Comment: @TomD It's only on the server

Comment: stupid question, but are you running just ```rails console``` or rails ```console -e production```
This looks to me like it's trying to load some gem that's only in development group but it's not installed on the server

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same error while upgrading from Rails 4 to Rails 5 and it turned out to be a bad merge in my Gemfile.lock.

I re-bundled (`bundle update rails`) and now it's working again.

Answer (score -1):

Generate project with `rails new my_api --api`

```
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'

caches_action :index
```

And got error:

```
app/controllers/api/v1/traces_controller.rb:10:inclass:TracesController': undefined method caches_action' for Api::V1::TracesController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

UPD Ok, in case you application controller inherited from ActionController::API, just:

```
include ActionController::Caching in application_controller.
```